# React 16: Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in <body>

Tags: reactjs

Since upgrading to React 16 I get this error message:

`warning.js:33 Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in <body>.`

What is generally causing this error message and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Could you show some code?

Comment: If you see something unexpected after the upgrade please file issues and provide examples. Otherwise we have no way to know something is broken. Thanks!

Comment: @DanAbramov You are right. This turned out to be an issue unrelated to React, but since v16 it fails to hydrate when a client side script tag is injected (Browsersync) where a React component is expected, giving the error above. This did not seem to be the case in React v15. Fixed by moving the inserted script tag to the end of the body.

Comment: @AntonHolmquist can you explain more detail? what script did you move to the end of body. I am facing this warning now.

Comment: @AntonHolmquist Did you solved this ?

Comment: any solution for this yet???

Comment: For me (on `NextJS`) just deleting the build output directory `.next` and restarting the dev server made the problem disappear.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you use `ReactDOM.hydrate` to start web application, you will see this warning.

If your application does not use server-side rendering (`ssr`), please use `ReactDOM.render` to start.

Comment: The `suppressHydrationWarning={true}` prop can also be used on the rendered element. However, as documentation points, this prop must be used scarcely. The better solution is using `hydrate()` or `render()`  appropriately: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#hydrate

Comment: So, what is this warning for?

Answer (score 42):

If your HTML code is like

```
<table>
  <tr>
```

you can get this error.
To get around it, use the <tbody> tag like

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
```

Don't forget to close the tag(s)!

Comment: This was the case in next.js

Comment: I am working on legacy code, and in a long ternary condition, the "else" output is a "There's no results found..." but it was inside a `<div>` inside the parent `<ul>`. Fixed it by changing the `<div>` to `<li>`.

Comment: Solved for me, thanks

Answer (score 33):

If you're using Server Side Rendering like NextJS, delete recent code and compare if you've tried to access a variable directly inside of Component scope where DOM is not guaranteed yet. For me, it was:

```
import { i18n } from 'i18n'

export default function SomeComponent() {
    const initLanguage = i18n.language              <---- causing error

    return ...
}
```

If you need to access such properties, access it within [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), so as to make sure that `document` is already established by then. It is kinda equivalent to [`componentDidMount()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount):

```
import { i18n } from 'i18n'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export default function SomeComponent() {
    const [initlanguage, setInitLanguage] = useState('en')

    useEffect(() => setInitLanguage(i18n.language), [])

    return ...
}
```

Comment: hi @Lucia, what happened if I want to get data from useSelector() ? I can't call hooks inside useEffect. I'm having this problem too which ruin the css in Next.JS. THank you.

Comment: @rony Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67095637/11322237)

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be because of Browsersync inserting a script tag in the body on client side that does not exist on server side. Thus React fails to attach to the server render.

Comment: So what is the solution?

Comment: I don't use a body as container for React, but got this error too on hydrating. How do you fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I got this using material UI by trying to do `const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(process.browser ? window.location.search : '')` at the top of the react component in my NextJS app with material-ui SnackBar, I was able to remove the error by putting this in a `useEffect` hook.

Entire component for reference:

```
export default function SnackBarMessage() {
  const [requestLogin, setRequestLogin] = useState(false)
  const handleClose = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason === 'clickaway') {
      return
    }

    setRequestLogin(false)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    // had to move into a useEffect hook
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(process.browser ? window.location.search : '')
    const hasRequestLogin = Boolean(searchParams.get('requestLogin'))
    if (hasRequestLogin) {
      setRequestLogin(true)
    }
  }, [])
  return (
    <>
      {requestLogin && (
        <Snackbar open={requestLogin} autoHideDuration={6000} onClose={handleClose}>
          <Alert onClose={handleClose} severity='error' style={{ fontSize: '18px' }} elevation={6}>
            Please Log Back In
          </Alert>
        </Snackbar>
      )}
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: I also had this while in GatsbyJS. In my case I ended up using the location data from props instead.
https://css-tricks.com/how-to-the-get-current-page-url-in-gatsby/#method-2-get-the-href-property-of-location-data-from-props

Answer (score 1):

In my case I got an error when upgrading to Next.js 13, specifically when using `Drawer` from `@mui/material`. It seems switching to server side components is not easy.

```
return (
  <Drawer
    anchor="left"
    onClose={onClose}
    open={open}
    PaperProps={{
      sx: {
        backgroundColor: 'neutral.900',
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        width: 280
      }
    }}
    sx={{zIndex: (theme) => theme.zIndex.appBar + 100}}
    // 'persistent' or 'permanent' throws error 
    variant="temporary"
  >
    {content}
  </Drawer>
);
```

Comment: Hi Adilet, this is not an answer but a comment/question. Make sure to use the "Answer" textbox for actual answers to the original question. I'm not downvoting you at this point, but others will for sure :) .

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because of using `PersistGate`  and `react-loadable`.
if you using this libraries, you could use preloadAll instead of preloadReady

Answer (score 0):

In my case i installed REACTFUL and it do a render so different by default install:

***src/renderers/dom.js***

```
ReactDOM.hydrate(
  <App initialData={window.__R_DATA.initialData} />,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

***src/renderers/server.js***

```
const initialData = {
   appName: 'Reactful',
 };
return Promise.resolve({
   initialData,
   initialMarkup: ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
     <App initialData={initialData} />,
   ),
   pageData,
 });
```

**care with initialData!**

i fix it changed **dom.js** like it, attention to initialData is important:

```
const renderMethod = module.hot ? ReactDOM.render : ReactDOM.hydrate;
const initialData = {
  appName: 'Reactful',
};
renderMethod(
  <App initialData={initialData} />,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be caused because the client and server mismatch during HMR updates

I resolved that way:

const renderMethod = !!module.hot ? ReactDOM.render : ReactDOM.hydrate

```
const renderMethod = !!module.hot ? ReactDOM.render : ReactDOM.hydrate
renderMethod(
  <AppContainer>
    <Comp />
  </AppContainer>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If using Remix SSR hydration and you see an error like:

```
Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <head> in <html>
```

there is a known issue where browser plugins can cause this issue (you can verify it's plugins by trying to load the page in Incognito mode).

See this Github issue: https://github.com/remix-run/indie-stack/issues/184

Apparently you can disable this warning/error by adding `suppressHydrationWarning={true}` to your `<html>` tag but this didn't work for me

This is also described in Remix's Gotchas: https://remix.run/docs/en/1.14.3/pages/gotchas#md-browser-extensions-injecting-code

This has been a frustrating and known issue for a long time and I have no idea why the Remix team has still not fixed this :(

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you're trying to access a prop in a dom before is ready. You can use a structure like this:

```
{(variable) && sameVariable}
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm assuming you are using ssr. The warning is about attempting to render before there is a window object. You need to hydrate.

```
ReactDOM.hydrate(<App />, document.getElementById("home"))
```

What I don't understand, is that the App component is being served static by express. Why is it trying to render before it is served? Bring on the comments.