# React 16: Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in <div> due to State

Tags: reactjs, isomorphic-javascript, client-hints

I'm getting the following error using SSR

`Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in <div>.`

The issue is on the client when checking the browser width on component mount, and then setting the state of a component to render a mobile version of it instead.

But the server is defaulting the desktop version of the container as it is not aware of the browser width.

How do I deal with such a case? Can I somehow detect the browser width on the server and render the mobile container before sending to the client?

EDIT: For now I've decided to render the container when the component mounts. This way, both server and client side render nothing initially preventing this error.

I'm still open to a better solution

Comment: Duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46443652/react-16-warning-expected-server-html-to-contain-a-matching-div-in-body. Be sure if you are using the `React.hydrate()` method is because you are using SSR. If not use `React.render()`. You can also use the `suppressHydrationWarning={true}` prop on the rendered element. But don't overuse it.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This will solve the issue.

```
// Fix: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <a> in
const renderMethod = module.hot ? ReactDOM.render : ReactDOM.hydrate;
renderMethod(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <RoutersController data={data} routes={routes} />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: It is. In the end you should have to restart the server. However in the end if you're using the same components for client vs server, it wouldn't make a difference. If you however want auto-reload the browser on server updates as well, you still need to auto-reload the server.

Comment: how does this solve the problem? This seems that if hot module relaoding is enabled, just use the SPA method for client side rendering 

But in production builds, there would still be a problem of markup mismatch ?

Comment: what about in nextjs, coz there is no root id in public folder

Comment: What does this do?

Answer (score 22):

### Gatsby

A recent feature flag of [gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/) (introduced in v2.28, December 2020) ables to **server-side render** pages in dev environment.

This flag is set to `true` by default. In this case, you might see this error message in the console

```
Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in <div>.
```

You can disable this flag in `gatsby.config.js` file :

```js
module.exports = {
  flags: {
    DEV_SSR: false,
  }
}
```

doc : https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/v2.28/#feature-flags-in-gatsby-configjs

Comment: from the document: `DEV_SSR - Server-side render (SSR) pages on full reloads during develop. Helps you detect SSR bugs and fix them without needing to do full builds.` This fix the warning but disable other features.

Comment: this just solves the development mode warning, this would not avoid the markup difference if you are server side rendering in production.

Answer (score 10):

This message can also occurs due to bad code that doesn't render consistent content between your SSR and CSR, thus `hydrate` can't resolve.

For example SSR returns :

```
...
<div id="root">
   <div id="myDiv">My div content</div>
</div>
...
```

While CSR returns :

```
...
<div id="root">
    <div id="anotherDiv">My other div content</div>
</div>
...
```

The best solution in this case is not installing libraries or turning off `hydrate` but actually fix the inconsistency in your code.

Temporaryly removing `<script src="/react-bundle-path.js"></script>` from `index.js` can help to compare the exact content rendered by SSR with content rendered by CSR `hydrate`.

Answer (score 9):

The current accepted answer doesn’t play well with TypeScript. Here is what works for me.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
import React from "react"
import { hydrate, render } from "react-dom"
import BrowserRouter from "./routers/Browser"

const root = document.getElementById("root")
var renderMethod
if (root && root.innerHTML !== "") {
  renderMethod = hydrate
} else {
  renderMethod = render
}
renderMethod(<BrowserRouter />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

Comment: this solution worked for me, React/React-DOM ^16.13.0

Answer (score 3):

From https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/17443#discussioncomment-87097

> Code that is only supposed to run in the browser should be executed inside `useEffect`. That's required because the first render should match the initial render of the server. If you manipulate that result it creates a mismatch and React won't be able to hydrate the page successfully.
>
> When you run browser only code (like trying to access `window`) inside `useEffect`, it will happen after hydration

Answer (score 1):

[HTTP Client Hints](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/09/automating-resource-selection-with-client-hints) could help you with this.

[Another interesting article regarding Client Hints](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/01/leaner-responsive-images-client-hints/).

Comment: The link you provided is no longer working, please paste relevant information here for future reference.

Comment: @CorwinCZ thanks for notifying. I've updated the ling and added another one.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to use a middleware like [express-useragent](https://github.com/biggora/express-useragent) to detect the browser user agent.

Then, in the server side, create a `viewsize` like `{width, height}` by the following rules

```
if (ua.isMobile) {
  return {width: 360, height: 480}
}

if (ua.isDesktop) {
  return {width: 768, height: 600}
}

return {width: 360, height: 480} // default, and for bot
```

Then, it is still somehow a responsive design in SSR.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to place the "Provider of Redux" and "Toaster" within the body tag in the Root layout.

```
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
      return (
        <>
          <html lang="en">
            <body className={inter.className}>
            <Toaster position="top-right" reverseOrder={false} toastOptions={{ duration: 1000 }} />
              <StoreProvider>
                {children}
              </StoreProvider>
            </body>
          </html>
        </>
      )
    }
```