# Next.js Azure Media Player Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <video> in <div>

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, azure-media-services

In my Next.js app I would like to embed a media player with Azure Media Services.
I followed the set-up process in docs:

1. added these 2 tags in the custom Head component

```
<link href="//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/skins/amp-default/azuremediaplayer.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src= "//amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/azuremediaplayer.min.js"></script>
```

2. pasted this video tag in the page

   `<video id="vid1" className="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin" autoPlay controls data-setup='{"nativeControlsForTouch": false}'> <source src='//amssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/3b970ae0-39d5-44bd-b3a3-3136143d6435/AzureMediaServicesPromo.ism/manifest' type="application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml" /> </video>`

However, the media player doesn't work and I'm getting this error in the console

```
Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <video> in <div>.
```

I guess it has something to do with SSR.. How should I handle this problem?

Comment: You can refer to this post and hope to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46865880/react-16-warning-expected-server-html-to-contain-a-matching-div-in-div-due?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [next.js with react-router](https://dev.to/toomuchdesign/next-js-react-router-2kl8) to solve the issue.

In React, you can [check answers in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46865880/react-16-warning-expected-server-html-to-contain-a-matching-div-in-div-due?rq=1). After read the answer, I think we also can figure the problem by `BrowserRouter`.