# Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in Server side rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, server-side-rendering

I am new in server side rendering. I am trying to implement it like following but, it shows error.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import rootReducer from './reducers'
import './index.css'
import Main from './Main'

const preloadedState = window.__PRELOADED_STATE__

delete window.__PRELOADED_STATE__

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer, 
    preloadedState,
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
  );

ReactDOM.hydrate( 
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Main />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

server.js

```
import express from 'express';
import open from 'open';
import rootReducer from '../src/reducers'
import Main from '../src/Main';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'

var app = express();
const port = 4000;

app.use(express.static('dist'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const store = createStore(rootReducer)

    const html = renderToString(
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Main />
        </Provider>
    )

    const preloadedState = store.getState();
    res.send(renderFullPage(html, preloadedState))
});

function renderFullPage(html, preloadedState) {
    return `
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
      <body>
        <div id="root">${html}</div>
        <script>
          window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(preloadedState).replace(/</g,'\\u003c')}
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
    `
}

app.listen(port, function (err) {
  if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        open('http://localhost:' + port);
    }
})
```

When i try to run SSR it shows following error. I don't understand what i am doing wrong?

> **`Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in <div>.`**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'; 
import Content from './components/Content';
import PageNotFound from './components/PageNotFound'
import Movie from './components/Movie';

class Main extends Component {

    render() {   
        return ( 
            <div className="main">
                <Router>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path='/' component={Content} /> 
                        <Route path='/search/:query' component={Content} />
                        <Route path='/film/:id' component={Movie} /> 
                        <Route path='*' component={PageNotFound} />
                    </Switch>  
                </Router>      
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Main;
```

This is not duplicate of given link as i am using SSR. Then why should i use render instead of hydrate as i am using SSR?

Comment: Remove <!doctype html> in your html.

Comment: @NguyênNgôDuy It makes no difference.

Comment: where is you main component?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React 16: Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in <body>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46443652/react-16-warning-expected-server-html-to-contain-a-matching-div-in-body)

Comment: @NaeemShaikh I edited my question to add main. And as per your URL they told to change `hydrate` to `render`. But, why should i change as i am using SSR?

Comment: @ketan, How is your markup rendered in development mode? is it server side too? if it is client side, that might show you the warning. The warning actually means it is not able to find server rendered markup

Comment: @NaeemShaikh This is also for development. you mean i need to do some configuration for development mode?

Comment: No I mean, typically people configure the application in a way that for development they just use client side rendering, and for other environment use SSR. In such cases the warning often occurs due to use of hyrdate

Comment: @NaeemShaikh No haven't done such configuration.