# How do I get item from localstorage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, local-storage, next.js

I try to get an item from my localstorage with next.js without rerender my page.

I use this code:

```html
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core";
import { FC, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useStore } from "../hooks/ContextStore";
import { darkTheme, theme } from "../theme/theme";

import Navbar from "./navbar/Navbar";

const Layout: FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false);
  const store = useStore();

  useEffect(() => {
    setDarkMode(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("dark-mode")));
  }, [store.darkMode]);

  console.log("did render");

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={darkMode ? darkTheme : theme}>
      <Navbar />
      {children}
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

Because my useEffect update my state it is rendering the page twice when I turn on or off the dark mode state.

Is there a way to prevent it from rerender that much and accessing the localstorage?

Comment: How about when initializing state, set the value from localstorage
`const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("dark-mode")));`

Comment: And I think, you should look for changes (in useEffect's dependency array) in localstorage value, instead of state cause you're looking for change in the local storage value as you're updating that.

Comment: I can't access localstorage outside useEffect / componentDidUpdate with next.js

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54819721/next-js-access-localstorage-before-rendering-page

Comment: I already tried it with class component. componentDidMount is useless because it won't get updated state.

With componentDidUpdate I get the same result as with useEffect - it still rerender the app.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, because your state value is alway going to be from the localstorage, then you don't need to store it in the state.
You can just do something like so:

```
const isClient = typeof window !== undefined;
const Layout: FC = ({ children }) => {
  const store = useStore();
  const darkMode = isClient && JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("dark-mode"));

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={darkMode ? darkTheme : theme}>
      <Navbar />
      {children}
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
export default Layout;
```

If you really want to store in the state, then you should update the dependency array in useEffect to look for updates in the localstorage value, not the state because you'll be updating the state.

```
const storageDarkMode = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("dark-mode"));
useEffect(() => {
  setState(storageDarkMode);
}, [storageDarkMode])
```

Comment: Thank you,

but because I'm using next.js, it is impossible to access the localstorage outside useEffect \ componentDidUpdate

Comment: the window object is only available when you're on the client side and you can check using this `const isClient = typeof window !== undefined;` I've updated answer with this

Comment: Thank you for your comment,

I've tried it but yet, it did not worked. I uploaded an image.

It still says the window object is not defined

https://ibb.co/SJVhJYT

Comment: How about turning isClient to function or moving it inside the component

Comment: It return the same result - window object in not defined. And it doesn't matter if it's inside the function component or outside.