# In NextJS, if setting "use client" on layout.jsx, will the children props lack SSR capability

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, next.js13

I have sub categories of products, and I want to use some hooks to add a border on the selected category for additional clarity. There will be 3 child pages in this example.
My question is: by turning the layout.jsx into a "use client" component, will the children lose out on SSR capabilities, and ultimately, SEO (the product information is crucial to web crawlers & cannot be sacrificed.)
    I cannot seem to find a straight answer if each page is independent of one another, or if nesting pages under a client component will have a direct effect. Please advise, and thank you for your time.

layout.jsx code:

```
"use client"
import Link from 'next/link';
import Image from "next/image";
import img from 'public/images/category/products/X1.png';
import img2 from 'public/images/category/products/X2.png';
import img3 from 'public/images/category/products/X3.png';
import { useRef, useState } from 'react';


export default function ProductSubCategoryLayout({ children }) {
    const [border1, setBorder1] = useState(false);
    const [border2, setBorder2] = useState(false);
    const [border3, setBorder3] = useState(false);

    const ref1 = useRef();
    const ref2 = useRef();
    const ref3 = useRef();

    const handleSelect = () => {
        if (ref1.current.name === '1') {
            setBorder1(true)
        } ... {}
    }

            return (
                <>
                    <h1>Product1 Product2 Product3</h1>
                    <div className="flex flex-row flex-wrap items-center justify-center gap-4">
                        <Link onClick={handleSelect} useref={ref1} className={`underline text-secondary btn flex flex-col my-2 ${border1 ? 'border border-secondary border-dashed' : ''}`} href={'/category/products/X1'}>Product1<Image className='mx-auto h-16 w-auto' src={img} alt="desc" /></Link>
                        <Link onClick={handleSelect} useref={ref2} className={`underline text-secondary btn flex flex-col my-2 ${border2 ? 'border border-secondary border-dashed' : ''}`} href={'/category/products/X2'}>Product2<Image className='mx-auto h-16 w-auto' src={img2} alt="desc" /></Link>
                        <Link onClick={handleSelect} useref={ref3} className={`underline text-secondary btn flex flex-col my-2 ${border3 ? 'border border-secondary border-dashed' : ''}`} href={'/category/products/X3'}>Product3<Image className='mx-auto h-16 w-auto' src={img3} alt="desc" /></Link>
                    </div>
                    {children}
                </>
            );
        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74992326/does-use-client-in-next-js-13-root-layout-make-whole-routes-client-component/75480826#75480826

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/client-components)

> "use client" is used to declare a boundary between a Server and Client Component modules. This means that by defining a "use client" in a file, all other modules imported into it, including child components, are considered part of the client bundle.

Comment: just to be 100% here, I have the "/" home page set to "use client" so I can have a product layout toggler & set the user light/dark preference from local storage. There is a product "Card" component that lists the product categories on the home page with links to each category. The "Card" links will go into a layout based on the category selected and the user can select a product. So you are positive that every product link stemmed from that <Card /> component will no longer be a server component? If this is the case, how do I approach UI components that link to pages that need SEO?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54819721/next-js-access-localstorage-before-rendering-page) (or other) questions could help.    If that setting is all you need, why not use a cookie instead of local storage?    Maybe `useEffect` to change the rendering after loading?   If you specify 'use client', that component (and therefore children) won't render on the server.  How could it since the server doesn't know about the user's localStorage in their browser?   What do you see rendering from the page on the server exactly?   Is there a way to re-arrange with important elements SSR?

Comment: I am glad you mentioned "What do you see rendering from the page on the server?", this investigation gave me the information I needed. And yes, the server is rendering the pages linked (and their data) from the use client components.