# ReactSSR: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in <body>

Tags: reactjs

Sorry to interrupt you guys to check my question, I have searched abot my question in stackoverflow and read this before: [same question as mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46443652/react-16-warning-expected-server-html-to-contain-a-matching-div-in-body)

It mentioned this way to solve this warning, but I don't think this is a really good way to handle the question: **suppressHydrationWarning={true} prop can also be used on the rendered element. However, as documentation points, this prop must be used scarcely. The better solution is using hydrate() or render() appropriately**.

So, here's my trouble when I use React SSR:

1. I start up nodejs server, and then I request a route in browser.
2. When server received my request, it should be returned server render 
   template to browser.
3. I can see elements are rendered in first screen which means dom are successfully mounted in .
4. When I click a element which will trigger route in configuration can also render.For now, everything is all right.
5. Here comes a thing: when I refresh page in browser which route calls '/text1' or '/text2' will also comes a warning like my question's title: Expected server HTML to contain a matching  in .
6. I suspect whether between my route in nodejs and some particular code in client didn't handle well which caused my question.

Here's my particular code[fake]:

// app.js

```js
const http = require('http')
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

const demo = require('./demo')
const clientScripts = demo('Client')
let scriptsTag = ''
clientScripts.map((script) => {
 scriptsTag += `<script src=${script}></script>`
})

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
 res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
 res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","*");
 
    // ssr
    const ssrObj = require('./static/entry/serverEntry')
    const dom = ssrObj.inital('server').dom
    const store = ssrObj.inital('server').store
    // const title = ssrObj.inital('server').title
    console.log('in: ', dom)
    res.setHeader("Content-Type","text/html;charset=utf-8");
    res.end(`
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>React & React Router4 SSR</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <!-- server side -->
                <div id="root">${dom}</div>
                <script>window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(store)}</script>
                <!-- ok with client side -->
                ${scriptsTag}
            </body>
        </html>
    `);
});
server.listen(1234, () => {
 console.log('开始监听1234端口')
})
```

// demo.js

```js
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')
let targetFile = ''

// suppose webpack configuration are ok, its' server output set in '/dist'
const fileList = fs.readdirSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'))
const container = []

module.exports = (params) => {
    fileList.map((file) => {
        const ext = path.extname(file).slice(1)
        if (ext === 'js') {
            const reg = new RegExp(`${params}`,"gim");
            if (reg.test(file)) {
                container.push(file)
            }
        }
    })
    return container
}
```

// /entry/serverEntry.js

```js
require('babel-polyfill')
require('babel-register')({
    presets: [ 'env' ]
})
const App = require('../common/initalEntry')
module.exports = App
```

// /entry/client.js

```js
require('babel-polyfill')
require('babel-register')({
    presets: [ 'env' ]
})
const App = require('../common/initalEntry')
App.inital('client').dom
```

// /common/initalEntry.js

```js
import React from 'react';
// dom
import {hydrate} from 'react-dom'   // client side use hydrate to replace render in react16
import {renderToString} from 'react-dom/server'
// router
import {StaticRouter, BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
// store
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import * as reducers from '../store/reducers'
import { App } from './App'

export function inital (url = '') {
    if (url === 'server') {
        console.log(1, url)
        const serverStore = createStore(reducers.counter)
        return {
            dom: renderToString(
                <Provider store={serverStore}>
                    <StaticRouter location={url} context={{}}>
                        <App type={url} />
                    </StaticRouter>
                </Provider>
            ),
            store: serverStore
        }
    } else if (url === 'client') {
        console.log(2, url, App)
        const clientStore = createStore(reducers.counter, window.__PRELOADED_STATE__)
        delete window.__PRELOADED_STATE__

        return {
            dom: hydrate(
                <Provider store={clientStore}>
                    <BrowserRouter>
                        <App type={url} />
                    </BrowserRouter>
                </Provider>
                , document.getElementById('root')
            ),
            store: clientStore
        }
    }
}
```

// common/App.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom'

class Text1 extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <div>i am text1.</div>
        )
    }
}

class Text2 extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div>i am text2.</div>
        )
    }
}

export class App extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
    }
    componentDidMount () {
        console.log(this.props, '<<<<<<<')
    }
    goTo () {
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <Link to="/text1">go text1</Link>
                <Link to="/text2">go text2</Link>
                <Route path="/text1" component={Text1}></Route>
                <Route path="/text2" component={Text2}></Route>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Above all, these are my configuration about react ssr which causes this question.Thanks to reviewing my question and pls give me some idea to handle this question.I will very apprciated to your help.

Here's my whole code: [just viewing and running the server/ directory is ok](https://github.com/LeungKaMing/Stark/tree/master/server)

Again, thanks for your help.

---

I deleted the code in App.js, then no longer show the warning, here's my modify:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Route, Link} from 'react-router-dom'

export class App extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
    }
    goTo () {
        console.log('click me')
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <p onClick={this.goTo.bind(this)}>123</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// I finally solve this problem when I find something a litte bit strange in /common/initalEntry.js
import React from 'react';
// dom
import {hydrate, render} from 'react-dom'
import {renderToString} from 'react-dom/server'
// router
import {StaticRouter, BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
// store
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import * as reducers from '../store/reducers'
import { App } from './App'

export function inital (type, url = '') {
    if (type === 'server') {
        const serverStore = createStore(reducers.counter)
        return {
            dom: renderToString(
                <Provider store={serverStore}>
                    {/* What I pass in location is a empty value which calls 'url' which causes me a lot of time to figure out what happened.The right way is pass the request url received by node.js server to 'location', then no more warning */}
                    <StaticRouter location={url} context={{}}>
                        <App />
                    </StaticRouter>
                </Provider>
            ),
            store: serverStore
        }
    } else if (type === 'client') {
        // ...ignore
    }
}
```

Comment: Please define it!