# React get state from Redux store within useEffect

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

**What is the correct way to get state from the Redux store within the `useEffect` hook?**

```
    useEffect(() => { 
        const user = useSelector(state => state.user);
    });
```

I am attempting to get the current state within `useEffect` but I cannot use the `useSelector` call because this results in an error stating:

`Invariant Violation: Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.`

I think I understand why as it breaks one of the primary rules of hooks.

From reviewing [the example](https://codesandbox.io/s/9on71rvnyo) on the Redux docs they seem to use a `selectors.js` file to gather the current state but this reference the `mapStateToProps` which I understood was no longer necessary.

Do I need to create some kind of "getter" function which should be called within the `useEffect` hook?

Comment: can you explain your answer right here please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58159108/react-get-state-from-redux-store-within-useeffect#comment102714614_58159273

Comment: In short... the `useSelector` should be called before the `useEffect`. This way we have the value and can conditionally handle it within the side-effect.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Don't forget to add `user` as a dependency to `useEffect` otherwise your effect won't get updated value.

```
const user = useSelector(state => state.user);
useEffect(() => { 
   // do stuff     
}, [user]);
```

Comment: if you have in your input field the prop: value={values.userName} , and you use this in your do stuff section: values.userName= auth.userName;  Then the value is not updated in the field, but appears in the redux tab. Any upgrade?

Comment: @JonathanOrrego it's hard to tell without a code snippet, please paste the code and i may be able to help you out.

Answer (score 9):

You can place `useSelector` at the top of your component along with the other hooks:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  ...
  const user = useSelector(state => state.user);
  ...
}
```

Then you can access `user` inside your `useEffect`s.

Comment: That doesn't ensure the data is loaded before the first render... Which is the entire point of `useEffect`

Comment: `useEffect` doesn't ensure that the data is loaded.
Normally your redux state will have an initial value, and when the data is loaded you would update the state by dispatching some action and handling it with on of your reducers, which will re-render your component, then you will have the loaded data inside it.

Comment: You will need to handle both cases inside your component, before and after the data is loaded

Comment: Sorry, I meant (if I understand correctly) the `useEffect` hook is there to perform side-effects (such as calling data) similar to how `componentDidMount` used to work.

Comment: So is there no way to ensure that the redux store is called prior to the initial render?

Comment: Redux store is called before the initial render, but with its initial value.
If you could edit your question with more details about what you are trying to achieve, then maybe I can answer you better.

Comment: I think perhaps I was misunderstanding the issue. I had a component erroring due to a `null` value. Which I had interpreted as the component's `const` is `null`. But it must be that the default state was `null`. So by setting my component to conditionally render based upon a set value solves it :) Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Sheixt thanks for the question because the answers here have reaffirmed what I know about Redux data and initial render. Your solution is correct. ALWAYS do conditional checks for your redux data.

Comment: @Sheixt I'm having the same issue with a component crashing because of an undefined value that uses `useSelector`. Would you be able to expand how you fixed it?

Comment: I would suggest using optional chaining (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to solve potentially undefined values. Ensuring that you have a default value set for your reducer is a helpful fallback as an alternative. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 8):

I found using two useEffects to works for me, and have useState to update the user (or in this case, currUser).

```
const user = useSelector(state=>state.user);
const [currUser, setCurrUser] = useState(user);

useEffect(()=>{
  dispatch(loadUser());
}, [dispatch]);

useEffect(()=>{
  setCurrUser(user);
}, [user]);
```

You have to use currUser to display and manipulate that object.

Answer (score 6):

You have **two** choices.

1 - If you only need the value from store once or 'n' time your useEffect is called and don't want to listen for any changes that may occur to user state from redux then use this approach

```
//import the main store file from where you've used createStore()
import {store} from './store' // this will give you access to redux store

export default function MyComponent(){
   useEffect(() =>{
      const user = store.getState().user;
      //... 
   },[])
}
```

2 - If you want to listen to the changes that may occur to user state then the recommended answer is the way to go about

```
const MyComponent = () => {
 //...
  const user = useSelector(state => state.user);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    //...
  },[])
 //...
}
```

Comment: Instead of importing store, you could also use useStore (https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usestore)

Comment: Yes, but useStore is a hook and hooks can not be used inside functions or other hooks. So we'll have to declare useStore on the component level, where as store.getState can be accessed with in functions. So its a better way to access store only when needed.

Comment: With `useStore` you also access the store only when needed. You just pass it as dep to hook and call getState inside it. It's better approach than exposing store as you did imho.
```const MyComp = () => {
  const store = useStore();
  useEffect(() => {
    store.getState().foo.bar
  }, [store]);
}```

Comment: Thanks for including the first, low tech option! I'm going with it until I can upgrade to react-redux 6+ and switch to `useSelector`.

Answer (score 2):

```
const tournamentinfofromstore=useSelector(state=>state.tournamentinfo)
useEffect(() => {
console.log(tournamentinfofromstore)
}, [tournamentinfofromstore])
```

So the problem is that if you change the state inside the useEffect that causes a rerender and then again the useEffect gets called "&&" if that component is passing data to another component will result in infinite loops.and because you are also storing that data in the child component's state will result in rerendering and the result will be infinite loop.!!

Answer (score 2):

Although it is not recommended, you can use `store` directly in your component, even in the `useEffect`.

First, you have to export `store` from where it is created.

```
import invoiceReducer from './slices/invoiceSlice';
import authReducer from './slices/authSlice';

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    invoices: invoicesReducer,
    auth: authReducer,
  },
});
```

Then you can import it to a `React Component`, or even to a `function`, and use it.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { store } from './store';

const MyComponent = () => {
  useEffect(()=> {
    const invoiceList = store.getState().invoices
    console.log(invoiceList)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default MyComponent
```

- You can study the `API` for `Store` in [here](https://redux.js.org/api/store).
- You can also see why this approach is not recommended in
  [here](https://redux.js.org/faq/store-setup#can-or-should-i-create-multiple-stores-can-i-import-my-store-directly-and-use-it-in-components-myself).
- Or, if you are interested in using `redux store` outside a `react component`, take a look at this [blog post](https://daveceddia.com/access-redux-store-outside-react/).

Answer (score 1):

To add on top of @Motomoto's reply. Sometimes you depend on store to be loaded before useEffect. In this case you can simply return in if the state is undefined. useEffect will rerender once the store is loaded

```
const user = useSelector(state => state.user);

useEffect(() => {
  if(user === undefined){
    return}else{ 
    // do stuff
}}, [user]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue, The problem to the useSelector is that we cant call it into the hook, so I can't be able to update with the action properly. so I used the **useSelector variable as a dependency to the useEffect** and it solved my problem.

```
const finalImgData_to_be_assigned = useSelector((state) => state.userSelectedImg);
useEffect(()=>{
console.log('final data to be ready to assign tags : ', finalImgData_to_be_assigned.data);
}, [finalImgData_to_be_assigned ])
```