# How to update data for react table

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-table-v7

I am trying to refresh the data in my redux store just before rendering my table. I call useEffect to do the refresh with the hope that useSelector will get the update when the call to the rest sevice returns.  I am feeding the data to react table's useTable hook. When I add the call for useEffect I put the page into an infinite refresh calling useSelector over and over on data but I don't see why. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Here is my component, the redux state functions work fine.  I am not showing the actual table here only the call to useTable hook.

```
  function RecurringPublicationTable(props) {
 
      const dispatch = useDispatch();

      // This will get called one time to refresh the recurring publishing data
      useEffect(() => {
        console.log("UseEffect");
        dispatch(getRecurringJobs());
      }, []);

      // This should get the data from store and subscribe.
      const data = useSelector((state) => {
        console.log("UseSelector");
        return state.recurringPublisher.recurringPublishJobs;
      });

 


      const columns = [
      {
        Header: "Name",
        accessor: "recurringJobName",
      },
      {
        Header: "Publish Location",
        accessor: "publishLocation",
      },
    ];

    // This should get the data ready for the table, but fails with max depth exceeded
    const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow } =
      useTable({
        columns,
        data,
      });

    return <div>Hello Ken</div>;
  }

export default RecurringPublicationTable;
```

Comment: i hope this will helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58159108/react-get-state-from-redux-store-within-useeffect

Comment: I think you need to either move the `columns` declaration ***outside*** the component, or memoize it with the `useMemo` hook. As-is it's redeclared each render cycle and the docs specify that both `columns` and `data` need to me memoized (https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useTable#table-options).

Answer (score 0):

I tried the suggestions but the result was still the same with constant re-render.

I figured out that I could get the desired affect of being able to refresh the data just before rendering the table by moving the table to a component and then have another component do the useEffect and then render the table component when the effect is completed.  I am also not sure why useMemo is needed for columns or the data. I see the documentation but it seems to work without wrapping it.

```
const RecurringPublicationTableContainer = (props) => {
  
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const isLoading = useSelector((state) => {
    console.log("The state is:", state);
    return state.recurringPublisher.isrecurringPublishJobsLoading;
  });

  console.log("Are we loading?:",isLoading);

  // This will get called one time to refresh the recurring publishing data
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("UseEffect");
    dispatch(getRecurringJobs());
  }, []);

  return isLoading ? <p>Loading...</p> : <RecurringPublicationTable />;
};

export default RecurringPublicationTableContainer;
```

Then RecurringPublicationTable component becomes

```
function RecurringPublicationTable(props) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();


  const data = useSelector((state) => {
    console.log("The state is:", state);
    return state.recurringPublisher.recurringPublishJobs;
  });

const columns = [
      {
        Header: "Name",
        accessor: "recurringJobName",
      },
      {
        Header: "Publish Location",
        accessor: "publishLocation",
      },
    ];

const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow } =
    useTable(
      {
        columns,
        data,
      },
      useFilters,
      useSortBy
    );
```