# How do I tell what file this error is coming from?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, jsx

I'm somewhat new to next.js and I'm getting this error. I've looked at every `<a>` tag I have in all my files and they all have a corresponding closing `</a>` tag. Am I not understanding this error properly? The only other thing I can think of is they want all my `<a>` tags to be wrapped inside of a `<div>` but I don't know why that would be required.

Error:
*Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching `<a>` in `<div>`.*
`react-dom.development.js?ac89:67`

Also where is this error being thrown from because they only reference they give is to a react-dom file that I think gets generated when next converts my code to something the browser can read (not 100% sure that's what the file is though)

[screenshot of error inside chrome dev tools console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8K92.png)

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46443652/react-16-warning-expected-server-html-to-contain-a-matching-div-in-body

Comment: for better debugging, you should install it on your code editor let us say you're using VSCode, try installing eslint or alike.

Comment: @jrran90 I'll install those and try it out thanks

Comment: Just read. it says that your links in NavBar->div->Link->a not match to this rendered on server.  So you have different data on server than in browser. put console log and check what data is in your terminal and what data shows on browser console.

Comment: This is not an error, it's simply a warning. It happens because the contents generated on the server by Next.js don't match what gets rendered on the browser. The issue comes from your `NavBar` component, could you add the code of that component to the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the DOM from `MyApp > App > Div > Navbar > Div > Link > a

I had this error. You need to wrap your Image in an  tag so it looks like this

```
<Link>
    <a>
        <Image>
    </a>
</Link>
```